# arc4random in NSNumber giving negative values?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, arc4random

I'm creating a random number and storing it in a NSNumber object like this:

```
NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:arc4random_uniform(2^32-1)];
```

I also tried:

```
NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:arc4random_uniform(4294967295)];
NSNumber *index = @(arc4random_uniform(4294967295));
```

At some point I'm also assigning the number 1 like this:

```
NSNumber *index = @(1);
```

This should give me only positive numbers.

Later on, I print out these numbers like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", index];
```

This gives me some negative values for the random numbers and 1 is being printed as 1. So I though maybe if I do:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", index.unsignedIntValue];
```

I'll get only positive numbers - which I do - but now 1 is suddenly being printed as some large positive number, also.

What's going on here? How can I correctly store a u_int32 (which arc4random returns) in a NSNmber and make sure that they are only positive?

Comment: I should add that the reason I'm using NSNumber to store the index value is that it's being used in an NSManagedObject entity. The attribute of that entity is set to "Integer 32" (there's no Unsigned Integer 32 available in the data model).

Comment: How are you printing the string that you get from your last snippet? Getting a large positive number for `(@1)` doesn't make any sense. Could it be that you're not using the correct format specifier (`%@`) when you print the string?

Comment: Btw, note that an unsigned 32 bit integer can contain larger values than one that is signed (not sure if that makes any difference for Core Data though).

Comment: I'm actually assigning the index number to a uitextlabel like this:

    textlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", index];

or

    textlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", index.unsignedIntValue];

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:arc4random_uniform(exp2(32)-1)];
```

I never get any negative numbers. `arc4random_uniform(x)` always returns a number between 0 and x, and the stringvalue of the NSNumber generated from it is correct.

EDIT: replaced exp2(31) with exp2(32)

Comment: I've also switched to using 2^31-1 instead of 2^32-1 now, but that means I only have half the numbers available and I don't understand why 2^32-1 gives negative numbers sometimes...

Comment: Sorry it was a typo of mine. You can use `exp2(32)` and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment that the index is stored in a Core Data entity as an "Integer 32" attribute, and I assume that is where the problem comes from.

Core Data dynamically generates getter and setter methods for all attributes (and relationships) of managed object classes. These accessor methods are different from the "usual" @synthesized accessor methods which are backed up by an instance variable.

For an "Integer 32" attribute, Core Data uses a (signed) integer for the attribute, and when you set a value, it is just cast or truncated to `int`. Example:

```
e.index = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:0xFFFFFFF0U];
// This would give the same result:
// e.index = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:0x1234FFFFFFF0LL];
NSNumber *val = e.index;
NSLog(@"value=%@, type=%s", val, [val objCType]);
// Output: value=-16, type=i
```

The output `type=i` shows that the value contains an `int`.

If you need unsigned integers in the range `0 .. 2^32-1`, then you can either (as you already did) use `unsignedIntValue`:

```
unsigned x = [val unsignedIntValue];
```

or store the attribute as "Integer 64".

*Remarks:*

- I am fairly sure that this is not a problem of `arc4random_uniform`.
- In your first code example `arc4random_uniform(2^32-1)`, you should note that `^` is exclusive-or, not exponentiation.